# How to transform employee attendence from rows to columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables, lets say, tblEmployees and tblAttendence. Employees table only contains employee codes and names, and attendence tables contains entry for each day for each employee if it is absent or not.

I post my test script with this question with 5 dummy records for employee and 30 rows in attendence table for each employee for a month (june 2017), so attendence table will have total 150(5x30) rows. I need the output in a tabular form showing employee names in each row but each day will appear in separate column. In my test script I did this for only 7 days with using left outer joins to same table with different day condition.

Here is the script:

```
----create dummy tables for 'Employee', and 'Attendence'
declare @tblEmployee table(
EmployeeID int,
EmployeeCode varchar(10),
EmployeeName varchar(255)
)

declare @tblAttendence table(
AttendenceID int identity(1, 1),
EmployeeID int,

AttendenceDate date,
AttendenceDay int,

Absence int
)


-----insert dummy records in both tables
declare @EmployeeID int = 1
declare @EmployeeCode varchar(10) 
declare @EmployeeName varchar(255) 

declare @CountEmployee int = 1
declare @CountDays int = 1


declare @UserYear int = 2017
declare @UserMonth int = 5

declare @DateFirst date = '1 jun 2017'
declare @DateLast date = '30 jun 2017'

declare @DateCurrent date = @DateFirst

while @CountEmployee <= 5
begin

    set @EmployeeID = @CountEmployee  
    set @EmployeeCode = ('E00' + CAST(@CountEmployee as varchar(10)))
    set @EmployeeName = ('Emp_Name_' + CAST(@CountEmployee as varchar(10))) 

    insert into @tblEmployee(
        EmployeeCode ,
        EmployeeID ,
        EmployeeName
        )   

    select 
        @EmployeeCode as EmployeeCode ,
        @EmployeeID  as EmployeeID ,
        @EmployeeName as EmployeeName;


    set @DateCurrent = @DateFirst
    set @CountDays = 1

    while @DateCurrent <= @DateLast
    begin

        insert into @tblAttendence(
            EmployeeID ,

            AttendenceDate ,
            AttendenceDay,
            Absence 
            )   

            select 
            @EmployeeID  as EmployeeID ,

            @DateCurrent as AttendenceDate ,
            day(@DateCurrent) as AttendenceDay,
            CAST(ROUND(RAND(),0) AS BIT) as Absence 

            set @DateCurrent = DATEADD(day, @CountDays, @DateFirst)
            set @CountDays = @CountDays + 1

    end

    set @CountEmployee = @CountEmployee + 1

end

-------at this points, we have 2 tables, 
-------tblEmployee contains 5 dummy records


----this query will do the actual job
----i.e, tranform attendence data against each employee for each day


select 
e.* 
,t1.Absence as Day1
,t2.Absence as Day2
,t3.Absence as Day3
,t4.Absence as Day4
,t5.Absence as Day5
,t6.Absence as Day6
,t7.Absence as Day7

from @tblEmployee e
left outer join @tblAttendence t1 on t1.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID and t1.AttendenceDay = 1
left outer join @tblAttendence t2 on t2.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID and t2.AttendenceDay = 2
left outer join @tblAttendence t3 on t3.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID and t3.AttendenceDay = 3
left outer join @tblAttendence t4 on t4.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID and t4.AttendenceDay = 4
left outer join @tblAttendence t5 on t5.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID and t5.AttendenceDay = 5
left outer join @tblAttendence t6 on t6.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID and t6.AttendenceDay = 6
left outer join @tblAttendence t7 on t7.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID and t7.AttendenceDay = 7
```

Now I have to do same work with full month days, means 30 columns required against employee record and using this technique I have to copy paste same code.

Is it a right approach for solving this problem or is there any better solution?

Comment: expected output

Comment: Expected output is same, when you run this script, it will display 7 columns for 7 days, I need similar with 30 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can repeat the table joins multiple times, using pivoting technique as below can get the desired output for 30/31 days of the month

Hope it helps

```
select e.*,dc.*
from @tblEmployee e
left join (select EmployeeID,[1] as Day1, [2] as Day2, [3] as Day3, [4] as 
Day4, [5] as Day5,   
                         [6] as Day6, [7] as Day7, [8] as Day8, [9] as Day9, [10] as Day10, 
                         [11] as Day11, [12] as Day12, [13] as Day13, [14] as Day14, [15] as Day15, 
                         [16] as Day16, [17] as Day17, [18] as Day18, [19] as Day19, [20] as Day20, 
                         [21] as Day21,[22] as Day22,[23] as Day23,[24] as Day24,[25] as Day25,[26] as Day26,
                         [27] as Day27,[28] as Day28,[29] as Day29,[30] as Day30,[31] as Day31
                from (select EmployeeID,Absence,AttendenceDay
                      from   @tblAttendence) d
                      pivot (max(Absence)
                              for AttendenceDay  in ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], 
                                                    [6], [7], [8], [9], [10],
                                                    [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], 
                                                    [16], [17], [18], [19], [20],
                                                    [21], [22], [23], [24], [25],
                                                    [26], [27], [28], [29], [30],[31])) as pvt) as dc
 on dc.EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId
```

Comment: Thanks @Bhagyesh, it have less repetition of code than the posted script.

Answer (score 0):

Just Run this cte and we will get Query in message Then copy and run the code along with your you will get you expected out put

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)
;With cte
AS
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(Order by (SELECT 1)) AS Rno
FROM master..spt_values

)
,Ct2 AS
(
SELECT Rno FROM cte WHERE Rno <=30
)
SELECT DISTINCT  @SQL=CONCAT('SELECT e.*,',
STUFF((SELECT ', '+' t'+CAST(Rno AS VARCHAR(10))+'.Absence AS [Day'+CAST(Rno AS VARCHAR(10))+']' FROM Ct2 i
  FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,''),'  FROM @tblEmployee e',
  STUFF((SELECT '  '+' LEFT OUTER JOIN @tblAttendence t'+CAST(Rno AS VARCHAR(10))+' ON t'+CAST(Rno AS VARCHAR(10))+'.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID AND t'+CAST(Rno AS VARCHAR(10))+'.AttendenceDay ='+CAST(Rno AS VARCHAR(10)) FROM Ct2 i
  FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,''))
FROM Ct2 o

PRINT @SQL
```

Here one more method is Dynamic sql process

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @RunCommand TABLE(RunCommand nvarchar(max))
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max),
        @SQL2 nvarchar(max),
        @FullSql nvarchar(max)
SET @SQL='
---create dummy tables for ''Employee'', and ''Attendence''

declare @tblEmployee table(
EmployeeID int,
EmployeeCode varchar(10),
EmployeeName varchar(255)
)

declare @tblAttendence table(
AttendenceID int identity(1, 1),
EmployeeID int,

AttendenceDate date,
AttendenceDay int,

Absence int
)


-----insert dummy records in both tables
declare @EmployeeID int = 1
declare @EmployeeCode varchar(10) 
declare @EmployeeName varchar(255) 

declare @CountEmployee int = 1
declare @CountDays int = 1


declare @UserYear int = 2017
declare @UserMonth int = 5

declare @DateFirst date = ''1 july 2017''
declare @DateLast date = ''31 july 2017''

declare @DateCurrent date = @DateFirst

while @CountEmployee <= 5
begin

    set @EmployeeID = @CountEmployee  
    set @EmployeeCode = (''E00'' + CAST(@CountEmployee as varchar(10)))
    set @EmployeeName = (''Emp_Name_'' + CAST(@CountEmployee as varchar(10))) 

    insert into @tblEmployee(
        EmployeeCode ,
        EmployeeID ,
        EmployeeName
        )   

    select 
        @EmployeeCode as EmployeeCode ,
        @EmployeeID  as EmployeeID ,
        @EmployeeName as EmployeeName;


    set @DateCurrent = @DateFirst
    set @CountDays = 1

    while @DateCurrent <= @DateLast
    begin

        insert into @tblAttendence(
            EmployeeID ,

            AttendenceDate ,
            AttendenceDay,
            Absence 
            )   

            select 
            @EmployeeID  as EmployeeID ,

            @DateCurrent as AttendenceDate ,
            day(@DateCurrent) as AttendenceDay,
            CAST(ROUND(RAND(),0) AS BIT) as Absence 

            set @DateCurrent = DATEADD(day, @CountDays, @DateFirst)
            set @CountDays = @CountDays + 1

    end

    set @CountEmployee = @CountEmployee + 1

end
'
SET @SQL2='
;With cte
AS
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(Order by (SELECT 1)) AS Rno
FROM master..spt_values

)
,Ct2 AS
(
SELECT Rno FROM cte WHERE Rno <=31
)
SELECT DISTINCT  CONCAT(''SELECT e.*,'',
STUFF((SELECT '', ''+'' t''+CAST(Rno AS VARCHAR(10))+''.Absence AS [Day''+CAST(Rno AS VARCHAR(10))+'']'' FROM Ct2 i
  FOR XML PATH ('''')),1,1,''''),''  FROM @tblEmployee e'',
  STUFF((SELECT ''  ''+'' LEFT OUTER JOIN @tblAttendence t''+CAST(Rno AS VARCHAR(10))+'' ON t''+CAST(Rno AS VARCHAR(10))+''.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID AND t''+CAST(Rno AS VARCHAR(10))+''.AttendenceDay =''+CAST(Rno AS VARCHAR(10)) FROM Ct2 i
  FOR XML PATH ('''')),1,1,''''))
FROM Ct2 o
'
INSERT INTO @RunCommand
EXEC( @SQl2)

SELECT @SQL2=RunCommand FROM @RunCommand

SET @FullSql=@SQL+@SQL2

PRINT @FullSql

EXEC(@FullSql)

SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

Comment: Since I am using SQL 2008 R2, it is giving me error: "'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name."

Comment: Then use '+'  instead of concat  ,change it